# Opsworks Chef 12.0 instance status start_failed but working

Tags: amazon-web-services, boot, aws-opsworks

We have an instance that has EBS (for boot performance) behind ELB . The current scenario whenever the instance exhaust in memory it will reboot with EBS the boot time is cut of 50% (down to 4mins) with thorough stress testing in N of times reboot the instance comes in a start_failed status. Now we checked the logs:

```
[2016-03-21T17:06:28+11:00] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge...
[2016-03-21T17:06:28+11:00] INFO: *** Chef 12.7.2 ***
[2016-03-21T17:06:28+11:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 2965
[2016-03-21T17:06:31+11:00] INFO: HTTP Request Returned 404 Not Found: Object not found: chefzero://localhost:8889/nodes/tmainsite3.localdomain
[2016-03-21T17:06:31+11:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to [] from CLI options
[2016-03-21T17:06:31+11:00] INFO: Run List is []
[2016-03-21T17:06:31+11:00] INFO: Run List expands to []
[2016-03-21T17:06:31+11:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for tmainsite3.localdomain
[2016-03-21T17:06:31+11:00] INFO: Running start handlers
[2016-03-21T17:06:31+11:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
[2016-03-21T17:06:31+11:00] INFO: HTTP Request Returned 404 Not Found: Object not found:
[2016-03-21T17:06:31+11:00] INFO: Loading cookbooks []
[2016-03-21T17:06:31+11:00] WARN: Node tmainsite3.localdomain has an empty run list.
[2016-03-21T17:06:31+11:00] INFO: Chef Run complete in 0.074774713 seconds
[2016-03-21T17:06:31+11:00] INFO: Running report handlers
[2016-03-21T17:06:31+11:00] INFO: Report handlers complete
```

Seems empty to me.. I understand what happens in a state when it stalls the booting due to a delay of agent service in a VPC but I think this is different.. it is start_failed and auto-healing does not work on it.. so therefor it will not reboot and go back to health check..

We tried direct access and the instance is working we can see our app working there and we checked the load balancer .. the instance is not there there is 0/0 , I assume this should be out of service right?

Please help.. we are kinda lost.. I know there are lots of happening in here.. I am happy if they can be explained .

Thanks!

EDIT: Adding logs from /var/log/aws/opsworks/opsworks-agent.keep_alive

```
[2016-03-21 17:03:09]  INFO [opsworks-agent(1379)]: keep_alive: Reporting keepalive. (0.991 sec)
[2016-03-21 17:04:09] DEBUG [opsworks-agent(1379)]: keep_alive: Performing keepalive
[2016-03-21 17:04:10]  INFO [opsworks-agent(1379)]: keep_alive: Reporting keepalive. (0.972 sec)
[2016-03-21 17:05:10] DEBUG [opsworks-agent(1379)]: keep_alive: Performing keepalive
[2016-03-21 17:05:11]  INFO [opsworks-agent(1379)]: keep_alive: Reporting keepalive. (1.276 sec)
[2016-03-21 17:06:11] DEBUG [opsworks-agent(1379)]: keep_alive: Performing keepalive
[2016-03-21 17:06:12]  INFO [opsworks-agent(1379)]: keep_alive: Reporting keepalive. (0.987 sec)
[2016-03-21 17:09:07]  INFO [opsworks-agent(1384)]: keep_alive: Initializing Instance Service client with credentials from IAM instance profile.
[2016-03-21 17:09:08]  INFO [opsworks-agent(1384)]: keep_alive: Running on AWS OpsWorks instance 1420ff17-a4db-4c2f-9c48-5190918e8518
[2016-03-21 17:09:08] DEBUG [opsworks-agent(1384)]: keep_alive: Performing keepalive
[2016-03-21 17:09:09] ERROR [opsworks-agent(1384)]: keep_alive: Access denied to the OpsWorks instance service
[2016-03-21 17:10:39] DEBUG [opsworks-agent(1384)]: keep_alive: Performing keepalive
[2016-03-21 17:10:40] ERROR [opsworks-agent(1384)]: keep_alive: Access denied to the OpsWorks instance service
[2016-03-21 17:12:10] DEBUG [opsworks-agent(1384)]: keep_alive: Performing keepalive
[2016-03-21 17:12:11] ERROR [opsworks-agent(1384)]: keep_alive: Access denied to the OpsWorks instance service
[2016-03-21 17:13:41] DEBUG [opsworks-agent(1384)]: keep_alive: Performing keepalive
[2016-03-21 17:13:42] ERROR [opsworks-agent(1384)]: keep_alive: Access denied to the OpsWorks instance service
[2016-03-21 17:15:12] DEBUG [opsworks-agent(1384)]: keep_alive: Performing keepalive
[2016-03-21 17:15:13] ERROR [opsworks-agent(1384)]: keep_alive: Access denied to the OpsWorks instance service
```

Comment: 1. Have you check why your instance is "started_failed"?  You may use "describe-service-errors" to see what happen.

2.  As for the ELB,  it should because of the "started_failed" so it doesn't attach the instance to ELB.

Comment: @BruceLi wow! `describe-service-errors` I haven't seen that in document..   will try to use this.. We have figure it out , after multiple times of rebooting.. somehow it changes the opsworks-agent id making the service  unable and goes to start_failed. In order to fix this, we have a shutdown recipe that stops the agent so that whenever the ec2 boots up it makes a new opsworks agent